# Rspec bypass inner function and return mock data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

In rails I am writing a test for a controller method `search_backups` with `Rspec`:

```
      def elastic_mongo_lookup(search_term) 
        devices_ids_from_elastic = ConfigTextSearch.search search_term
        puts devices_ids_from_elastic
        device_ids = devices_ids_from_elastic.map { |device| device._source.device_id }
        csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
          Device.where(:_id.in => device_ids).each do |device|
            csv << [device.logical_name, device.primary_ip]
          end
        end
        return csv_string
      end

  def search_backups
    authorize! :read, :custom_report
    csv_string = elastic_mongo_lookup params[:search_term]
    if csv_string.blank?
      flash[:notice] = "No results were found"
      redirect_to reports_path
    else 
      render text: "DeviceID, primary_ip\n" + csv_string
    end
  end#search_backups
```

---

```
  describe "try controller method" do
    let(:reports_controller) { ReportsController.new }
    before do
      allow(CSV).to receive(:generate).and_return("1234", "blah")
      allow(ConfigTextSearch).to receive(:search).and_return(['"hits": [ {"_source":{"device_id":"54afe167b3000006"}]'])
      allow(:devices_ids_from_elastic).to receive(:map).and_return('54afe167b3000006')
      stub_request(:get, "http://localhost:9200/mongo_index/config_files/_search?q=").
        with(:headers => {'Expect'=>'', 'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.9.1'}).
        to_return(:status => 200, :body => '', :headers => {})
    end

    it "allows people to search backups" do
      reports = double(ReportsController)
      post 'search_backups'
    end
  end
```

The issue is that `ConfigTextSearch.search search_term` returns a elasticsearch ORM object.. which means I can't stub it because the `.map()` method on `devices_ids_from_elastic.map` is unique with it's nested `_source` method.

How could I bypass `elastic_mongo_lookup` entirely and just return a mocked `csv_string` to `search_backups`?

Answer (score 1):

In an RSpec controller test, `controller` is defined as the controller under test.  You can therefore achieve what you're asking about with the following:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:elastic_mongo_lookup).and_return('whatever string you choose')
```

Comment: For some reason it still uses the real `elastic_mongo_lookup` instead of the mock one.

Comment: Then I'd confirm that `controller` is defined as the controller under test.